# Error on line 18, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I'm doing a flutter bootcamp course. The task was to add the english_words dependency but while implementing that I ran into an error in the dev_dependencies as it came from the code stub.

How can I fix this error?

```dart
name: xylophone
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  # Use Audioplayers dependency version 0.17.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

[image: pubspec.yaml error message in dev_dependencies]

Comment: Can you include you `pubspec.yaml` as snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I added it as a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for error message, there was an indentation issue. I think you didn't save the `pubspec.yaml` file. Copy and paste the full snippet and save it then run `flutter pub get` or use the extension you've used

```yaml
name: xylophone
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  english_words: ^4.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  # Use Audioplayers dependency version 0.17.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pubspec.yaml given by @yeasin Sheikh.. Also if you unfamiliar with using pubspec. The easiest way to add a package is to run

```dart
flutter pub add english_words
```

in terminal.
This will add the latest version of english_words package to your pubspec with proper indentation.

Comment: It makes the same error when I type that. The error is on a different line than the english_words. The error is on line 18 "Dev_dependencies"

Comment: Did you type this in terminal?